# Performance of Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, css, svg, fonts, font-awesome

A web development company develops a website for me, which uses 12 icons from Font Awesome 5.15.3. They use SVG with JavaScript. After using Google PageSpeed Insights, I find the Font Awesome JavaScript becomes the performance bottleneck.

I then find ["Performance & Font Awesome"](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/performance). But this does not provide much information on each method. I try to contact the support but get no responses by now. So I am trying to test with these methods by myself, such as SVG Sprites and individual SVG icons, meanwhile sharing my understanding of the pro and con of each method in performance.

**Note:** I will only consider the case that I [host Font Awesome on my own server](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself).

1. SVG with JavaScript: Based on my debug in Chrome DevTools, it seems that the javascript code is just find the patterns like  and replace them with the corresponding svg icons. This will be time-consuming if the DOM tree of the whole page is large. Also why bother to let the JavaScript to do the task if one can just insert SVG icon to the location manually? I guess there are 3 reasons:

a. `<i class="fas fa-camera"></i>` is short(29 characters only) and more convenient to use than using an individual SVG Icon(normally 500 bytes) or a SVG Sprites(3 lines with total 88 characters).
b. It will not bloat the source HTML page too much.
c. It is good only if the same icon is used for many times, like below:

[image]

2. Web Fonts with CSS

In this method, one needs to include the Font Awesome font files with @font-face rule. And the download of the large Font Awesome font files will become the bottleneck of the performance. As far as I know, if I only use 16 icons from 1000 icons, there are no way to create a new font file containing only the 16 icons from the existing one.

3. SVG Sprites: This method seems to be great for my case. I can create a small svg file containing only the 16 icons I need. Then use the following way to include it in the HTML page:

```
        <svg>
          <use xlink:href="fa-brands.svg#facebook"></use>
        </svg>
```

Though it requires 3 lines than 1 line(SVG with JS). It is still short, even if the icon is used for multiple times. I guess the disadvantage of this method is one plan to use many icons, for example, 100 icons. In such a case, the svg file will be large and become the performance bottleneck when downloading it.

Another disadvantage may be due to that to search in the SVG Sprite file, it will take some time, since the individual icons in SVG Sprite file is not indexed in any way.

4. Individual SVG icons: Embedding the SVG icon data to the HTML source will be the most efficient  way in performance. But each SVG icon file will be about 500 bytes to 3KB, which will bloat the HTML file greatly. Also it is not good if the icon will be used in the page for many times, as in such a case, the HTML source will become huge.

Also "the browser cannot cache inline SVG as it would cache regular image assets, so pages that include the image will not load faster after the first page containing the image is loaded." based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web

5. SVG + CSS: THis method is not mentioned in Font Awesome, but are widely used. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web for different ways to add SVG to webpage, including SVG + CSS.

Please kindly advise if my understandings are correct or not. THank you very much!

**Update:**

I find one interesting comparison on their site: [Web Fonts vs SVG](https://fontawesome.com/v6.0/docs/web/dig-deeper/webfont-vs-svg)

**Update 2**

I add another popular method which uses SVG + CSS

Comment: Honestly, I'd go with svg sprites. Even if you have a hundred icons, it's just plain text, if it's in a separate file it will be cached, etc...

Answer (score 0):

From my own personal experience I can tell you that I prefer to use the 12 icons approach VS anything else. Web fonts were great solution when not all major browsers were well performing svg standard. But today it's nonsense to use a bloating icon font when you just use 12 icons from there. If you want to be able to measure the impact of leaving the font and using the svg icons instead go and take a look to the performance and speed of my own web site here https://www.simbiosis-dg-apps.com. I tell you that except for the 2 pictures of myself and my partner every thing else that you will see is svg. Sometimes embedded into the html and most of the time called through the img tag. For the icons I use a similar method like the one that is used to set icons from an icon font but using my own css system. If want a better picture see this answer [How to Replace the Web Font with SVG icon in CSS(Font Awesome)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765863/how-to-replace-the-web-font-with-svg-icon-in-cssfont-awesome/68766858#68766858)

Comment: alancc, I didn't realized until now that both questions were asked by you. Get assured that the use of the svg approach will be a thousand times better than any other approach

Comment: Thank you very much. In such a case, whether I should use SVG Sprites or embedding individual SVG Icon to the HTML source directly?

Comment: The use of a sprite is quite good solution (I don't like it anyway due to the extra work of positioning every icon, also it can be resource comsuming as the entire svg will be rendered just to use a single icon in a certain location) but I rather preffer to use as I said, single icon called through the **i** tag. See it in my ansewr to your other question, there's the code example

Comment: Thank you very much. What you provide is another method CSS + SVG Icon, not mentioned in Font Awesome official site, but very interesting to try.

Comment: It's a method to get rid of the icon font and all it's caveats. It allows you to use just the amount of icons that you need. Resul:less weight, less overload when fetching assets from server, faster performance. But it's up to you if you want to go on using the icon font. At least I can say that my PageSpeed Insights never showed any bottleneck on my projects.

Comment: I've been using font-awesome 5 for a few years now, and take advantage of tree shaking and using only the fonts that I need. However when my site is server rendered or ultimately rendered in the browser, there is a large amount of css bloat for all the font-awesome api tags, such as spin, rotate, etc.  

.svg-inline--fa {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: inherit;
        height: 1em;
        overflow: visible;
        vertical-align: -0.125em;
      }
      .... goes on for 10 pages.

Any way to solve this? bloats most of my pages with this css.